# Keeping an Index After Sorting in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I recently started using Pandas (Python 3.5) in Jupyter Notebook. I set an index and then sorted, which works the first time. But when I try to sort again I get an error message and my index variable isn't recognized.

**Read in File**

```
raw_df = pd.ExcelFile('MyFile',parse_dates=True).parse('Raw Data')
```

**Set Index**

```
raw_df = raw_df.set_index('OrderId')
raw_df = raw_df.sort_values(by='WeekOrdered')
raw_df.head()
```

As I said above, when I run the cell above the first time, it works fine. But when I try to run again, I get the error message.

```
C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py
in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    1944             try:
-> 1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    1946             except KeyError:

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
(pandas\index.c:4154)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
(pandas\index.c:4018)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
(pandas\hashtable.c:12368)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
(pandas\hashtable.c:12322)()

KeyError: 'OrderId'
```

Any ideas why I can't run this cell again?

Comment: Because the first time you run the cell, `OrderId` is set as index and there is no column named `OrderId` anymore. The second time you try to set it as index, it can't find `OrderId`. Create a data frame with a different name so that the `raw_df` doesn't change.

Comment: You are repeatedly using the same name raw_df before and after sorting. Try with a new name like raw_df_sorted when using sort.

Comment: You could also do `set_index('OrderId',drop=False)`.  You'll avoid that error although I don't really understand why you would go through the code more than once without re-reading in the excel data (?)